# Cant append items to a list using conditionals

Tags: python

**So I am trying to append items to various lists based on .isdigit() as a conditional as well as the presence of a string...**

For example:

```
h="hello"

if h.isdigit()==False and "hello" in h:
    print(h)
```

> hello

^This is valid..

However, when I try to incorporate this-

The following is valid:

```
user = "jerry"
names = ['max1','max2','jerry1','jerry2','jerry3','steph1','steph2','steph3',"susanB","susanC"]
max = []
jerry = []
steph = []
susan = []

for name in names:
    if user in name:
        for char in name:
            if char.isdigit() and "jerry" in name:
                jerry.append(name)

print(jerry)
```

> ['jerry1', 'jerry2', 'jerry3']

But not:

```
user = "jerry"
names = ['max1','max2','jerry1','jerry2','jerry3','steph1','steph2','steph3',"susanB","susanC"]
max = []
jerry = []
steph = []
susan = []

for name in names:
    if user in name:
        for char in name:
            if char.isdigit()==False and "susan" in name:
                susan.append(name)

print(susan)
```

> []

Expected:

> ['susanB','susanC']

Can someone please explain what is causing this behavior and how to rectify it?

Comment: In the second example you still have `user = "jerry"`.

Comment: Why do you check if the user is in `name` twice? Or rather, that's what you seem to have intended to do, except you hardcoded one as `'susan'` and the other as `user = 'jerry'`, as Mark mentions.

Comment: Also what exactly are you trying to do here? There's likely a much easier solution using regular expressions, if you're willing to learn a little bit about regex.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to change the name variable in the beginning. Change it to **susan** and desired about will be obtained.

The current program is essentially appending items if both **jerry** and **susan** are present in the string.

Comment: Wowza, been staring at this for 10 mins and I didnt see that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer above already explains what the solution is, but I would like to provide a concrete code implementation of it combined with removing some redundant code pieces.

```
user = "susan" # You forgot to change this variable.
names = [
    "max1",
    "max2",
    "jerry1",
    "jerry2",
    "jerry3",
    "steph1",
    "steph2",
    "steph3",
    "susanB",
    "susanC",
]
max = []
jerry = []
steph = []
susan = []

for name in names:
    if user in name:
        for char in name:
            if char.isdigit():
                break

        susan.append(name)

print(susan) # Output: ['susanB', 'susanC']
```